# Interesting place in NSTask's source code

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa

In source code of the NSTask I've found interesting place in method waitUntilExit:

```
- (void) waitUntilExit
{
    NSTimer *timer = nil;

    while ([self isRunning])
    {
        NSDate  *limit = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 0.1];
        if (timer == nil)
        {
           timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.1
                                                    target: nil
                                                  selector: @selector(class)
                                                  userInfo: nil
                                                   repeats: YES];
        }

        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                                 beforeDate: limit];
        RELEASE(limit);
   }
   [timer invalidate];
}
```

I can't understand purpose of NSTimer here. And whose method class will be called?

Comment: Where did you find that code? Can you give a reference/link ?

Comment: https://github.com/timburks/gnustep-base/blob/master/Source/NSTask.m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timer target is `nil`, so the selector is actually irrelevant: You can send any message to `nil` which is then simply discarded.

The compiler only verifies that the selector refers to some known method, in this case the [`class`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/class) method of the `NSObject` protocol.

This dummy timer is necessary for the following `runMode` statement 
which otherwise could terminate immediately, as the [`NSRunLoop` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSRunLoop/runMode:beforeDate:)  states:

> If no input sources or timers are attached to the run loop, this method exits immediately and returns NO; otherwise.